# "cause":"INVALID_REQUEST","explanation":"Unexpected parameter 'shipping.address.city'"}

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, opencart-module, mastercard

I am using opencart. I have already build a module using mastercard payment gateway services. Currently am running on old API Version, which is 55. Now am planning to upgared my API version to latest. But in doccumentaion of mastercard, i found that there are chnages from API Version 63.

What i should be done.I just changed the API Version am getting following error

```
"cause":"INVALID_REQUEST","explanation":"Unexpected parameter 'shipping.address.city'"}
```